# How to get list of CLSIDs along with their associated COM Object names?

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch-file, powershell-5.0, powershell-3.0

Searching for the ways to generate or get the list of CLSIDs, I found this [link](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2019/06/hunting-com-objects.html), that actually does it.

But it's rather incomplete in my opinion, the complete list would include CLSIDs with their associated COM Object names, as mentioned in question.

How do I get such complete CLSIDs list ?

Comment: https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/06/27/pstip-get-a-list-of-all-com-objects-available/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PSChildName property like this:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Classes | Select-Object `(default`), PSChildName
```

Comment: have you run that code? i get a `(default)` column that contains _nothing at all_ ...